# Get parent property in child select in Powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell, smo

I want to include a parent level property in a child result set in Powershell and I can't figure out how to do it.  An example of what I want to do would be to include the ServerName as the first column of a pipe to get the DatabaseName and a list of Database properties of all the databases on the server similar to:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "SQLSERVER"

$s.Databases | select $s.Name, Name, AutoShrink, AutoClose
```

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do, (I could easily use the Database Parent property to get the $s.Name) but I have much more complex applications where I'd like to use this similar methodology and a Parent property isn't what I am after.  Also if I could alias the $s.Name to be ServerName and the $_.Name as DatabaseName it would be the ideal output.

EDIT:

I have spent two days searching for how to do this online and can't find any reference.  If you happen to Google/Bing/whatever the answer, if you'd also share what you used to find it I'd be really appreciative.  I generally can find the answers to stuff, but after two days I am just throwing good time after bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want the Parent property?

```
$s.Databases | select Parent, Name, AutoShrink
```

Edit:

```
$s.Databases | select @{Name="ServerPlatform"; Expression={$_.Parent.Platform}}, Name, AutoShrink
```

Comment: That works for this scenario, but I also said that I have more complex applications. I want to be able to get any property from the $s that I want, not just the Name. I just used that as a simple example because it required the least code.  That doesn't solve the second half of the problem, renaming them to ServerName and DatabaseName.

Comment: I must be oversimplifying it... so let's suppose you want the Platform property of the server.

Comment: And... if you don't want to bother naming it, just use the curly braces: `$s.Databases | select {$_.Parent.Platform}, Name, Autoshrink`

Comment: I'll give that a +1 but it doesn't solve the real problem, I want it to come from $s, not $_.  :-)

Comment: ok, using what you wrote, the $s.Name works in the brackets as well for the Expression.  Thanks a million.