# How to make condition for gettype()?

Tags: powershell, ssas

SQL Server 2017 databases come in 1400 level. However, the databases could contain different typenames (structured vs nonstructured) to display connection details

**Non structured**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.providerdatasource?view=analysisservices-dotnet

**Structured**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.structureddatasource?view=analysisservices-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.connectiondetails?view=analysisservices-dotnet

In the following script, I want to display the connection strings of databases, however, I am not sure how to make an if condition based on the type of the database's typename.

Pseudo code of what I want but I don't know how I can fill in the `gettype()` part:

```
#SSAS 1200-1400 
$AS = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$AS.Connect("server1")

foreach ($dbt in $AS.Databases){

  $dbName = $dbt.Name
  $dbName

If ($dbt.gettype(structured) -eq $true) #or IsStructured instead of -eq $true
  $dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails.ToString() 

Else $dbt.model.datasources[0].Connectionstring


}
```

...

```
$dbt.GetType()
```

[image: gettype]

```
$dbt | Get-Member
```

[image: gm]
[image: gm2]

Comment: I do not have a SQL AS system here. What is the output on screen of `$dbt.GetType()` ?

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld check edit i made and added picture

Comment: If you want to get specific SQL information, GetType() is not the way. GetType is a member method that can be found on all powershell variables providing basic information. It might be that a member function/method/property of $dbt can provide that information. You can discover the members like this `$dbt | Get-Member` I hope this helps

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld it gave me a bunch of methods/properties. check picture

Comment: my knowledge of SQL AS is lacking here. I suggest you add one or more tags to your question to get attention from SQL specialists

Comment: There is a Structured property in the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular namespace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.datasourcetype?view=analysisservices-dotnet . Maybe you can traverse the parent data of the Model property. Older post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151880/get-parent-property-in-child-select-in-powershell